# Display input fields only if ID exists in database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a PHP form in which I ask for the input of Customer ID. If the ID exists, then I allow the user to fill in further details about the customer such as his phone number, address etc. If the ID does not exist, I throw an alert saying that no such customer ID exists.

I have tried the following code without any fruitful results.

```
<style>
#hidden {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
  <input type="text" name="cust_id">
  <input type="submit" value="Add details" name="check_cust">

  <div id="hidden">
          <input type="tel" name="phone">
  </div>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['check_cust'])) 
{
    $id = $_POST['cust_id']
    if(idExistsInDatabase($id))
    {
    const obj = document.getElementById('hidden');
    obj.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

When I execute the above code, I get the following error:-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

I am new to web development and would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

EDIT: Never mind. I did it using AJAX.

Comment: You can't arbitrarily mix PHP and JS code like that. PHP runs on the server, JS runs in the browser. The basic idea is to check which `$_POST` data was supplied by the form, then display HTML accordingly (by echoing it or not). You can also remove the form's `action`; if you omit it, the form will send the data "to itself".

Comment: @ChrisG, I now get that I cannot mix PHP and JS code. Then, how do I solve the problem?

Comment: Here's example code: https://pastebin.com/Q4jmhSC3 (note that you should probably use a [session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) instead so you don't have to keep passing along previous data in hidden inputs; this is mostly about conditional output anyway)

Answer (score 1):

You're using JS Code inside PHP. You can't use like that.

How you can use is to use script tags inside echo in PHP. For example,

```
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('JavaScript code!');</script>";
```

Now to make your working change you portion of nested if like this below given :

```
if(idExistsInDatabase($id))
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = 'block';</script>";
}
```

Above code should do the job for you.

Comment: I tried out the above solution and got the error 'add_cust_details.php:83 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null'.

Comment: This is a bad idea and not the answer to OP's problem

Comment: @ChrisG, could you please help me out?